# Github Notifications: explicit vs general "PR Review Request"

Tags: github

I am working on a github repo with 20 developers. I want a notification if someone requests me or one of my groups. But I don't want to get a notification if there is a review request where I am not explicitly involved.

At the moment the "Notification" page is unusable for me, since there are far too many review requests which are not on my plate.

That's the overflowing page:

[image: github-notifications]

Reason for the overflow: I am part of the team "foo". If someone requests a review from my team, then I get a notification. Usually someone else is faster than me, but the notifications stays in the inbox.

If I have time for PR-reviews, I don't look into the notification inbox. I use "Pull Requests" at the top (right to "Search or jump to ...")

How can I filter the notifications automatically, so that review-requests are not in the inbox?

Comment: What about [`reason:assign reason:review-requested`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/viewing-and-triaging-notifications/managing-notifications-from-your-inbox#supported-reason-queries)?

Comment: Doesn't the "review requested" specify the reason why you were notified? Sounds like you *were* requested for review for all of these PRs, justifying the notifications

Comment: @jemand771 have you read "Reason for the overflow" in the question? My goal is to get rid of the old notifications automatically.

Comment: I have a similar problem where I'd like to exclude `review-requested` notifications which were created because a particular team's review (of which I am a member) was requested. I'd like to only get notifications if I was personally asked to do a review.